# SSH Maverick : Looking for files on the remote machine

Tags: ssh

I am using a Maverick SSH library to connect to the remote machine. Then I am trying to find a file or a group of files in the specific directory based on the wild card : abc*.txt

I tried to use SFTPClient ls(String str) method, however it didn't work :

```
try{
        String fileName = "/tmp/myDir/abc*.txt";
        SftpFile[] files = sftp.ls(fileName);
        if(files != null && files.length > 0)
          retCode = true; 
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Exception : " + ex);
    }
```

I am getting : No Such File exception.

Is there any way to find out whether the file/group of files exist on the remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this api https://www.sshtools.com/j2ssh-javadocs/com/sshtools/sftp/SftpClient.html?

As the javadoc states ls method takes a string path to a directory and not some sort of regular expression.

You can try programmatically listing each directory in your desired path and search the array of SftpFile(s) returned if that is what you need.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out about ls(String) method. Reading the directory into the array of SftpFile[] actually is not a good idea hence one may have thousands of files in it. I thought there was something else I hadn't seen.